# One color issue about render texture in unity

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, textures, render

I have creaeted a window on the UI to show spinning models which are rotating about their y axes. For most of the models, their color shown on the GUI are fine. However, for some models, the color shown on the GUI is transparent(just as the same as the GUI background's color.) For example, if I set my GUI background to be green color, then the model's color will be green on the GUI. In my project, all the models are buildings. I tried to change the color of the specific building(which has the color issue) from light yellow to be a dark color, then the color of it shown on the GUI is fine.But, if I change the color of it back to light yellow, then the color of it shown on the GUI will be the same as the GUI background's color which is green.

I used render texture to render a camera view on the UI, so users can see the spinning model through a camera's view.

Any one can tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Does this problem reproduce with specific models, or models with specific colors, or it reproduced completely randomly?

Have you tried using a second camera instead of render texture (just to test it)?

Comment: Yes, it seems like this problem happens only when I use light yellow color. Besides, only those models with light color will have the problem. However, all the models look fine in the camera view, that is why I didn't try to use a second camera to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I've solved this problem. I checked all the materials of the original model object. I found out that not all the colours of the materials are set to be diffused. After I changed all of them to be diffused, problem solved!